# TypeScript: add a new object into an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have the following data structure:

```
uiBundles:
[
    {
        "id": "tasks widget UI",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "tasks-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "berater widget UI",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "berater-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I would like to do is add a new uiUnit into this embedded array of objects. Here is my code:

add-new.component.ts:

```
uiBundles: UIBUndle[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBundlesService.getUiBundles().subscribe((value: UIBundle[]) => this.uiBundles = value);
}

addWidget(id: string): void {
    this.selectedUiUnits = this.uiBundles.filter((data) => data.id === id);
    let newWidget = { id: 'new', uiUnits: [{ id: 'new-widget', type: 'widget', roles:'MB' }] };
}
```

add-new.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let bundle of uiBundles">
  <button (click)="addWidget(bundle.id)"></button>
</div>
```

When I run this code, the result is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "tasks widget UI",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "tasks-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "berater widget UI",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "berater-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "new",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "new-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But what I am trying to do would be:

```
[
    {
        "id": "tasks widget UI",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "tasks-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            },
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "new widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "berater widget UI",
        "uiUnits": [
            {
                "type": "widget",
                "id": "berater-widget",
                "roles": "MB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can someone please help me, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Would better if you could keep the indentation in your code blocks.

Comment: code format improved

Comment: I can't see the place in your code where you are adding your new widget to the `uiBundles`. You are doing nothing with your `newWidget` variable, did you omit some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
addWidget(id: string): void {
    const index: number = this.uiBundles.findIndex((data) => data.id === id);
    const newUnits = [{ id: 'new-widget', type: 'widget', roles:'MB' }];

    this.uiBundles[index].uiUnits.push(newUnits);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding the new widget to the uiUnits array of the widget with the specified id but instead are creating an entirely new widget.

What you want is rather

```
addWidgetToBundleUnits(id: string) {
  const selectedBundle = this.uiBundles.find(bundle => bundle.id === id);
  const widgetToAdd = {id: 'new-widget', type: 'widget', roles: 'MB'};
  selectedBundle.uiUnits.push(widgetToAdd);
}
```